# TYPO3 - Scheduler doesn't run recurring tasks

Tags: ubuntu, web, terminal, typo3, scheduler

TYPO3 doesn't want to run recurring tasks in the scheduler, there are no problems when I run it manually. If it's late, it just gives the status "Late, will run next execution".

What I tried/checked:
- Chmod correct files
- Checked the setup script
- Checked the log
- www-data user is added
- Checked apache logs, nothing

I'm using TYPO3 6.2 beta5 running on ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add a cronjob that triggers the scheduler now and then. Otherwise just nothing will happen.

For example, after open your crontab for editing with `crontab -e` add:

```
*/15 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/bob/www/typo3/cli_dispatch.phpsh scheduler
```

Of course those paths needs to fit your php binary and your typo3 folder. With this cronjob your scheduler will be called every 15 minutes. Each time it will check if any scheduler tasks are late and if so, will start them.

You find the complete how-to [here](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/scheduler/latest/Installation/CronJob/Index.html) (from the official [scheduler documentation](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/scheduler/latest/Index.html)).

Comment: To run cli_dispatch.phpsh add a TYPO3 backenduser (BE-User) named "_cli_scheduler", use a random password. You do not need to remember this password, as you will never need it.

Comment: @Daniel @Daan I do not know if I should reopen the question but I used this solution and it only works for me when in the Install Tool => Configuration Presents => Extbase Object Cache active `Database cache backend`, since I am in development now appear several debug  messages all over time in the BE and in the FE, I have read that it is recommended to use the option APC or APCu but with this solution the task does not run automatically only manually. Please guide me on this and if it is the case to update the question or open a new one.